# Why does my laptop audio stop working when I'm on battery power?

Tags: laptop, audio, power-management

I've got a HP laptop running vista and recently the audio will cut out as soon as I remove the mains power. I've looked at the control panel power options and can't find anything that turns off the audio on battery power.

Anywhere else I can check to see what's happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check your power management profile/settings?

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem in Windows 7. I think its not due to low power, but rather due to a software bug. After I installed Windows 7 Service Pack 1, my problem was solved